# Is the object a vector?

Tags: c++, if-statement, vector

I am using a template typename recursive function. I would like at some point to ask if the object I am manipulating is a vector (a vector of anything). Something like the `is_vector` function below

```
template <typename TYPE>
void f(const std::vector<TYPE>& x)
{
   for (auto& element : x)
   {
      if (is_vector(element))
      {
         f(element);
      } else
      {
         g(element);
      }
   }
}
```

Is this feasible?

Comment: What about other types of container, like `std::array()`?

Comment: The question is indeed a duplicate. Thank you